# How to check this form properly filled out in an easier way?

Tags: php, javascript

I have a questionnaire of which one question offers five answer options. The user may tick three, and give those three a rating. To avoid misunderstanding, here is the HTML code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="option_1"> Option 1 (to be determined)</td>
        <td>
            <select name="">
                <option value="">as:</option>
                <option value="3">1st</option>
                <option value="2">2nd</option>
                <option value="1">3rd</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="option_2"> Option 2 (to be determined)</td>
        <td>
            <select name="">
                <option value="">as:</option>
                <option value="3">1st</option>
                <option value="2">2nd</option>
                <option value="1">3rd</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="option_3"> Option 3 (to be determined)</td>
        <td>
            <select name="">
                <option value="">as:</option>
                <option value="3">1st</option>
                <option value="2">2nd</option>
                <option value="1">3rd</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="option_4"> Option 4 (to be determined)</td>
        <td>
            <select name="">
                <option value="">as:</option>
                <option value="3">1st</option>
                <option value="2">2nd</option>
                <option value="1">3rd</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="option_5"> Option 5 (to be determined)</td>
        <td>
            <select name="">
                <option value="">as:</option>
                <option value="3">1st</option>
                <option value="2">2nd</option>
                <option value="1">3rd</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I need to be able to check that the user did not tick more than three options, and that the ratings 1st, 2nd and 3rd are only used once. I can check that with a javascript that checks each item separately, like this:

```
if (document.form_name.option_1.value != "") && 
(document.form_name.option_2.value != "") && 
(document.form_name.option_3.value != "") && 
(document.form_name.option_4.value != "") 
{alert('You can only tick three options'); return false};
```

but that would give a humongous script. Is there an easier way? It may be javascript or PHP. Preferably the latter, but I am not as proficient in PHP, so then I would need a rather ready-to-use script.

Thanks much in advance.

Comment: Javascript and PHP execute at two different times. You want a mixture of both for user-friendly validation. PHP on the server side is a must and JS is optional if you don't want to inconvenience the user with loading a new page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need PHP in this instance (although you should include server side validation like PHP because there is no guarantee that the validation JS is actually run on the client's browser. Possibly because of a malicious user, or maybe just because of one who doesn't have JS enabled).

You can make your JS shorter if you add some logic. Iterate through each of your questions. Within each question, count each of the checked checkboxes and when you are done see which ones have more than 3 checked.

```
var questions = document.getElementsByClassName('question'), numberChecked, answers;

for(var q = 0, qlen = questions.length; q < qlen; q++) {
    numberChecked = 0;
    answers = questions[q].getElementsByTagName('input');

    for(var a = 0, alen = answers.length; a < alen; a++) {
        if(answers[a].type == 'checkbox' && answers[a].checked) {
            numberChecked++;
        }
    }

    if(numberChecked > 3) {
        alert('You may only check 3 choices for question #' + (q + 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Much better answer than mine :)

Answer (score 0):

Created a method to validate using pure javascript:

```
    function innerValidate(){
    var inputs = document.form1.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var ddls = document.form1.getElementsByTagName("select");
    var checkedCount = 0, ddl, opsSelected = [], isValid = false;
    for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++)
    {
        if(inputs[i].type == 'checkbox' && inputs[i].checked == true)
        {
            if(++checkedCount >3){
                isValid = false;
                return isValid;
            }
            for(var j=0; j<ddls.length; j++)
            {
                if(ddls[j].name == inputs[i].name)
                {
                    ddl = ddls[j];
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(ddl.value && opsSelected.indexOf(ddl.value) == -1)
            {
                opsSelected.push(ddl.value);
            }
            else
            {
                isValid = false;
                return isValid;
            }
        }
    }
    if(checkedCount == 3)
    {
        isValid = true;
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/T784z/